# Is integrious a valid word?

Tags: word-usage

[The Macmillandictionary says it is](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/integrious), but I'm still unsure about its veracity.

The sentence in which I'd like to use it, is as follows :

***"Sometimes peer-pressure & the feeling of need to conform can hinder a person from remaining `integrious`.*"**

Comment: The [full (subscription-only) OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/97362?redirectedFrom=integrious#eid) has it marked as ***obsolete***. But even if you replaced it by a more "current" term (such as ***honest, moral, decent***), the sequence *...can hinder a person from remaining XXX* would not be ["felicitous"](https://www.yourdictionary.com/felicitous). If you like the word ***integrity***, consider something like *...can make it difficult to **retain one's integrity*** or similar. And it's just ***the need to conform*** - forget about including ***feeling of*** there.

Comment: A thousand mention of gratitude for accommodating & accounting my query, as well as introducing me to a foreign word(felicitous)! But, if it's not too much to ask, ma'am, may I know the reason why it could be beneficial to disregard **_feeling of_**?

Comment: My point about ***feeling of*** is essentially a *stylistic* choice. It adds nothing to the intended meaning, and it clashes with preceding "clipped" ***peer pressure*** (not hyphenated, just a shorter way of saying ***pressure from peers***). You could say avoiding ***can hinder a person from remaining X*** is also just a stylistic choice, but that second one would probably be classed as "clumsy, awkward" by more people than would agree with me regarding ***feeling of***. Both are "syntactically valid" - it's just a matter of whether they're "natural, idiomatic".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Valid" is a subjective thing here. It's obviously a valid adjective - although the spelling **integrous** seems to have significantly more use - but your question seems to be "is the word in common use?"

The answer to this is no. As a native speaker, I don't recall ever hearing it being used. Instead you will likely opt for a description that involves its noun counterpart:

> He is a man [of/with] great **integrity**.

Adjectival scenarios will tend to use a synonym or similar word to define the characteristics:

> He is an **honest**, **trustworthy** man [of great integrity].